# How to use multiple data sources in Eleventy

Tags: eleventy

I would like to be able to call more than one json file in an eleventy template page (gallery.njk).
I've tried putting everything into a nested json file 'collections.json' but its not working and i'd rather have it separated out anyway for manageability purposes.

I'm trying something like this, but it's not working:

```html
---
pagination:
    data: "collection1", "collection2"
    size: 1
    alias: image
permalink: "/gallery/{{ image.title | slug }}/"
---
```

Have also tried:

- data: collection1, collection2
- data: [ collection1, collection2 ]

This is what does work, but it only gives me 1 collection obviously:

```html
---
pagination:
    data: collection1
    size: 1
    alias: image
permalink: "/gallery/{{ image.title | slug }}/"
---
```

Comment: So to be clear, you aren't asking how to use multiple data files in Eleventy, but rather, how to use them in one particular pagination template. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, i guess that would be correct. I don't want to have to create a dozen templates because i have a dozen collections, i would like one template to display each collection from a different json files, if that makes sense?

Comment: But do you want one pagination or N pagination? It sounds like you want one, and as far as I know, you can only supply one data item. You could use addGlobalData to create a new data item that combines *other* ones. Keep in mind though that unless your data is pretty similar, your pagination template will get messy as it tries to handle rendering different things.

Comment: If you are sure you want to combine 2 or more collections, in theory you could use collections.all for your data, and use before to filter to two (or more) particular parts. Or, in your .eleventy.js, just make a new custom collection based on what you want.

Comment: Hi @RaymondCamden, thanks for taking the time to try solve this. It would be great if you could take a look at my git repo i have which will be easier to show/explain the issue. Any chance i could email it to you.. not sure what the rules are around sending links to repo's and not sure i want to post it here either.

Comment: I hope you don't mind Raymond, i sent you an email through your website with more details about the issue. It would be great if you could take a look whenever you get time. thanks :)